# Is it possible to add libraries from Node.JS and some libraries from angular.js and also from react.js in one javascript file?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, reactjs

I was wondering if it is possible to add multiple libraries from different JavaScript frameworks into one.

Comment: Yes, as long you can npm install it or import the correct files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is bundling.

[Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) are two fine tools for this job. webpack is used by angular 2+ so I would recommend it. Of course other options exist.